# Why is MySQL 5.7.17 giving me a syntax error on this JSON column?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm attempting to set up MySQL 5.7 in my Codeship deployment, as the JSON column type is used in this particular project. Among assorted other things, my deployment script runs the following:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeship/scripts/master/packages/mysql-5.7.sh)
```

(obviously it won't depend on someone else's script long-term, this is just for testing the deployment setup)

This installs MySQL 5.7.17, which I then use to create test databases:

```
/home/rof/mysql-5.7.17/bin/mysql -e 'create database test_db;'
// etc...
```

None of this is an issue. MySQL 5.7.17 is installed to the directory, and my application can successfully connect. My problem is this query:

```
create table `submissions` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `uuid` char(36) not null,
  `form_id` int unsigned not null,
  `data` json not null,
  `created_at` timestamp null,
  `updated_at` timestamp null
) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

This particular query errors out whenever I attempt to run my application's migrations. The error I receive is the usual *'check the manual that...'* error, finishing in *'near 'json not null,..''*. This leads me to believe that the json column is the cause of the syntax error.

Why? MySQL 5.7.17 supports json, does it not? I've confirmed it's the right version by running `/home/rof/mysql-5.7.17/bin/mysql -V`, which returns:

```
/home/rof/mysql-5.7.17/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for linux-glibc2.5 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Also of note is that the application I am deploying is a Laravel application. The migration is below:

```
Schema::create('submissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->uuid('uuid')->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedInteger('form_id');
    $table->json('data');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique('uuid');
    $table->index('form_id');
});
```

Comment: What does your migration file look like?

Comment: you can absolutely fine tune the query, just open up the migration and edit it before you run it.

Comment: Which ‍‍`migration` will cause an error message? Can you show it?

Comment: I added the migration file to the question!

Comment: Are you sure that you just didn't install mysql5.7. but an older version of it is running? What's the output of `SELECT VERSION()` from within your application (if that is possible)?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I seem to be running the pre-installed 5.6 version, even though my .env info is pointing to the 5.7 install. I'll need to check into why that's happening.